# mvn dependency:list -DoutputFile for Multi Module project

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-dependency-plugin

I have maven multi module project(parent and 2 child modules) and when i issue mvn dependency:list -DoutputFile="maven_dependencies.txt", output file only listing last module output. How to get output of all 3 modules output in **mvn dependency:list -DoutputFile="maven_dependencies.txt"** command?

Comment: It working for me. Which version of Maven and m-dependency-p are you used?

Comment: `mvn dependency:list -DoutputFile='${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}/maven_dependencies.txt' -DappendOutput`

Comment: I am using maven version: 3.3.9
maven-dependency-plugin version: 3.3.0
Please let me know what is the version of yours?
Thanks

Comment: Hi @AndreyB.Panfilov, I tried this option. But no luck. -Dappendoutput appending out to previous file content.

Comment: the main point was in `${maven.multiModuleProjectDirectory}`, in your case `dependency:list` creates `maven_dependencies.txt` in every submodule.

Comment: Yes you are right. Its creating maven_dependencies.txt in every submodule(just now i observed). Is there any way to combine that output.